# Add key value to array from inside map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, dictionary

I'm running a function that determines the distance between a users input lat lon and an arrays lat lon inside of a map, which is iterating through data returned from graphql. I cant figure out how to add the new key value pair back into the array.

```
const names = data?.venuesByCountry.map(v => (
    distance(latA, lonA, `${v.latitude}`, `${v.longitude}`),
     <>
    <ParagraphXSmall>{distA} km away</ParagraphXSmall>
    </>
  ))
```

so that `{distA}` essentially becomes `{v.distA}`
`v.distA:distA`

and i can then filter results based on distance from the user

have tried `.put()` and `.set()` possibly incorrectly, to no avail.

Thanks as always :)

Comment: do you want to add a [key, value] in your `array of objects`? If so you can `forEach` or make use of `map`.

Comment: @gorak yeah I want to add them as a key value pair to the array they're created inside

Comment: `var venuesByCountry =[{key1:'Value1', key2:'Value2'},{key1:'Value3', key2:'Value4'}];
    result = venuesByCountry.map(k=>({...k, distanceA:'someCalc'}));` Just an example, what it does add `distanceA` in your new array of objects. Afterwards you can also apply filter based on the new key.